Error adding private sharing PCS to public sharing PCS for share
I am attempting to use the open ai image API and send images.  Unfortunately, they don't let you send image data directly, instead, you have to save and share the image to the cloud, and send their API a link.
I am trying to save the image via icloud, and make it public.
Here are the Dashboard configuration steps I've taken
Here is my code:
import CloudKit
import Foundation

extension Data {
    func uploadToCloudKit(completion: @escaping (Result<URL, Error>) -> Void) {
        do {
            let containerIdentifier = try String.iCloudContainerIdentifier()
            let container = CKContainer(identifier: containerIdentifier)
            let publicDatabase = container.publicCloudDatabase

            // Create a record
            let record = CKRecord(recordType: "Image")

            // Save the image data to a temporary file
            let tempURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent(UUID().uuidString)
            try self.write(to: tempURL)

            // Create a CKAsset with the file URL
            let imageAsset = CKAsset(fileURL: tempURL)
            record["image"] = imageAsset

            // Save the record to CloudKit
            publicDatabase.save(record) { savedRecord, error in
                // Delete the temporary file
                try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: tempURL)

                if let error = error {
                    completion(.failure(GenericError("Error uploading image: \(error.localizedDescription)")))
                    return
                }

                guard let savedRecord = savedRecord else {
                    completion(.failure(GenericError("Failed to save record without error")))
                    return
                }

                let share = CKShare(rootRecord: record)
                let container = CKContainer.default()
                let modifyRecordsOperation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: [record, share])
                modifyRecordsOperation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { savedRecords, deletedIds, error in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if let error = error as? CKError {
                            let genericError: GenericError

                            switch error.code {
                            case .networkUnavailable, .networkFailure:
                                genericError = GenericError("Network issues: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                            case .quotaExceeded:
                                genericError = GenericError("Quota exceeded: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                            case .partialFailure:
                                if let partialErrors = error.partialErrorsByItemID {
                                    let partialErrorMessages = partialErrors.map { "Partial error for recordID \($0.key): \($0.value.localizedDescription)" }
                                    genericError = GenericError(partialErrorMessages.joined(separator: ", "))
                                } else {
                                    genericError = GenericError("Partial failure without specific errors: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                }
                            case .serverRecordChanged:
                                genericError = GenericError("Server record changed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                            case .notAuthenticated:
                                genericError = GenericError("Not authenticated: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                            case .permissionFailure:
                                genericError = GenericError("Permission failure: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                            default:
                                genericError = GenericError("Other error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                            }

                            completion(.failure(genericError))
                        } else if let shareURL = share.url {
                            completion(.success(shareURL))
                        } else {
                            completion(.failure(GenericError("Failed to save record without error")))
                        }
                    }
                }
                publicDatabase.add(modifyRecordsOperation)
            }
        } catch {
            completion(.failure(error))
        }
    }
}

When I po the error I get:
(lldb) po genericError
▿ GenericError
  - message : "Partial error for recordID <CKRecordID: 0x6000010dcf20; recordName=2D6350E1-F1BC-4CE9-89CE-35A1E52D259C, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>: Record <CKRecordID: 0x1239aa420; recordName=2D6350E1-F1BC-4CE9-89CE-35A1E52D259C, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__> will not be saved because of previous error in atomic zone, Partial error for recordID <CKRecordID: 0x6000010dcfe0; recordName=Share-E804AED9-AC79-445A-96B4-27EB2647A1AD, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>: Error adding private sharing PCS to public sharing PCS for share <CKRecordID: 0x1238956b0; recordName=Share-E804AED9-AC79-445A-96B4-27EB2647A1AD, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>: <CKError 0x122721e30: \"Internal Error\" (5005); \"You can\'t add a nil share PCS to a record PCS\">"

I am not sure what else needs to be done, but I keep getting this error.

You can send images directly to OpenAI. This is what I use:
# Get base64 string
base64_image = encode_image(image)
content = [
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": text_in
    },
    {
        "type": "image_url",
        "image_url": {
            "url": f"data:image/png;base64,{base64_image}"
        }
    }
]

messages.append({"role": "user", "content": content})

where image is the path to a png image held locally, and encode_image is defined with:
import base64

def encode_image(image_path):
    with open(image_path, "rb") as image_file:
        return base64.b64encode(image_file.read()).decode('utf-8')


    {
        "type": "image_url",
        "image_url": {
            "url": <your Data here>
        }
    }

I'm not sure where I can find sed encode_image method, however, is it setting the type to image_url, but then are you passing data as the value for the key "url"

I had included the definition just above (just a few cm above here).  I know that it seems weird to declare the image as a url, but that is the way they have designed it. All the code that you need is in the answer, and you should be able to test it very easily.
